# Fundamental group of a space with no one cell?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $X$ be a $CW$-Complex such that in the cell decomposition of $X$ there is no $1$ cell.Is there any 'easy' way to show that $\pi_1(X)$ is zero?

I am looking for a easy proof without using some big results like 'simplicial approximation theorem'

Comment: try to use seifert van kampen.

Comment: @ThomasRot Since i am new to fundamental groups,so i dont even have van Kampen theorem with me yet.

Comment: By "topological space" you probably mean a CW complex, otherwise the claim is trivially false. On the matter of substance, try to show that the n-sphere of dimension >1 is simply connected without using any "big results" (which are not really that "big"), like Seifert - Van Kampen theorem, or simplicial approximation theorem or Sard's theorem.  To the best of my knowledge, such proofs do not exist.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I know $S^n$ is simply connected for $n>1$ but how does this help?

Comment: @VictorBarg: Of course, but _how_ do you know this? Imagine yoy have a "Peano circle" which is a surjective continuous map from $S^1$ to $S^2$. How do you know that this map is null-homotopic?

Comment: @MoisheCohen: I read the proof given in Hatcher's algebraic topology book which does not use any 'big' results but i dont see how this solves my question?

Comment: @VictorBarg: Read Hatcher's proof again. What he uses is a form of the simplicial approximation theorem, he just does not call it this way (yet). The general approximation theorem works in a similar fashion, you just have more cells to worry about than one (as in the sphere case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47199/discussion-between-victor-barg-and-moishe-cohen).

Comment: Given that you're in the CW-category and talking about the $1$-skeleton of a space, I don't think you're going to get around using something along the lines of the cellular approximation theorem. But why wouldn't you want to use it? It's a very well-known result that's useful for exactly this sort of problem.

Comment: @anomaly: Since i have just started learning about fundamental groups so i don't have cellular approximation theorem with me yet. Thanks